# Update rate of `top`

Tags: configuration, software-recommendation, top

I've created the personal config file for `top` and I would like to change the update rate (the rate at which `top` updates data about the current processes). How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your personal config file will probably be stored in your home directory and called `.toprc` (in the Nautilus file browser, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or click `View` > `Show  Hidden Files` to show files that start with `.`). Assuming you have created it in the usual way (by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> while `top` is running), its contents will look something like this:

```
RCfile for "top with windows"       # shameless braggin'
Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=3.000, Curwin=0
Def    fieldscur=AEHIOQTWKNMbcdfgjplrsuvyzX
       winflags=62777, sortindx=10, maxtasks=0
       summclr=1, msgsclr=1, headclr=3, taskclr=1
Job    fieldscur=ABcefgjlrstuvyzMKNHIWOPQDX
       winflags=62777, sortindx=0, maxtasks=0
       summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem    fieldscur=ANOPQRSTUVbcdefgjlmyzWHIKX
       winflags=62777, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
       summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr    fieldscur=ABDECGfhijlopqrstuvyzMKNWX
       winflags=62777, sortindx=4, maxtasks=0
       summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=3
```

On the second line change the number (of seconds) in `Delay_time=3.000` to whatever you want it to be. For example, for very fast updating (which you should be aware will make `top` itself take up considerably more system resources), you could change it to `Delay_time=0.250`. Then `top` would update four times per second.